# Why data from Controller for Ajax request is null?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I just want to pass some Json Data to controller via Ajax. as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Ajax/MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: { mobile: mobile_no, generation_unit_id: generation_unit_id},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

But when I debug at controller data is null. My method at Controller is:

```
public IActionResult MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(String data)
    {
        //ViewBag.Result =  _generationUnitMobileService.MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(mobile,generationUnitId);
        return View();
    }
```

I inspect ***String data*** but it is null. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You are not sending anything named `data` - Delete the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', ` and then change the method to `MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(string mobile, string generation_unit_id)` (or better have a model containing those 2 properties)

Comment: Why don't you make use of ASP.NET MVC Model binding..? Also, your ajax call does not specifies whether its a get or post.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding JSON.stringify data and type as POST.

```
var data = { mobile: mobile_no, generation_unit_id: generation_unit_id };
data = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    url: "/Ajax/MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: "json",
    type : POST,
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method in the controller:

```
public JsonResult AjaxTest(int id )
{   
    return Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Call from JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serviceURL = '/YourControllerName/AjaxTest';

        $.ajax({               
            url: serviceURL,               
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {     
            alert(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
</script>
```